# How to break a for loop in spark udf

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

SO I have a udf like this:

```
def myfunc = {udf((A:mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]],B:mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]]) 
=>  breakable{for(i <- 0 to 2)yield( if (A(i)==B(i)) "U" //want to break here 
else "N" //break here)})}
```

it's return me multiple U or N's, I want it to return only one letter as a final result. How do I break out the for loop?

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do with the UDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exists` method tests if some predicate is true for at least one element in a collection:

```
if ((0 to 2).exists(i => A(i) == B(i))) "U" else "N"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
def myfunc = udf((A: mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]], B: mutable.WrappedArray[mutable.WrappedArray[String]])
=>  breakable{
    for(i <- 0 to 2) yield 
      if (A(i)==B(i)) {
        "U"
        break
      } 
      else {
        "N"
        break
      } 
     })
```